# gdal2tiles tile origin differences using Windows/OSGeo4W and Linux/GDAL

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles

I am getting different X and Y values for tiles from gdal2tiles.py when in a PC
(OSGeo4W - GDAL 1.9.2) environment and Linux (GDAL
1.10.1).  It seems to me that the newer 1.10.2 x's and y's are wrong (not respecting the specified origin).

Is this a bug, which result is correct, and how do I get them to
behave the same?

===

Details:
I've created a sample tileset on a PC in windows using the
tools from GDAL 1.9.2 in OSGeo4W for a map in projection
NZTM2000 (EPSG:2193).  The resulting tiles are
generated as-per my expectations, and the origin from which
the tiles are numbered is the origin of the projection
(+lat_0=0 +lon_0=173).

Having perfected this with a small map area, I switched to a
cloud server running linux and gdal1.10.1.  The process
appears to run successfully - tiles are generated, BUT the
tile x and y numbers are different.

After much stuffing around, I've realised that the x and y
values used match those used for the same geographic area
when using the default EPSG:4326.

During troubleshooting I have run the gdal2tiles on the same
single map sheet with the same command line options in both
environments, manually specifying the SRS in case the
definitions differ, and got two different results. 
I've also tested it using the built-in projection -s
EPSG:2193.

python gdal2tiles.py test.tif -s '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0
+lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80
+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs' -z 5-10

PC / Windows / Cygwin:
mbriggs@forestero
/d/OSGeo4W/maps_past $ ls test/11/
1116/  1117/  1118/
mbriggs@forestero
/d/OSGeo4W/maps_past $ ls test/11/1116
1303.png*  1304.png*
mbriggs@forestero
/d/OSGeo4W/maps_past $ 

Linux:
mbriggs@dev:~$ ls
test/11
2022  2023  2024  2025
mbriggs@dev:~$ ls
test/11/2022
767.png  768.png  769.png
mbriggs@dev:~$ 



mbriggs@dev:~$ gdalinfo
test.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test.tif
Size is 4193, 2861
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
        DATUM["unknown",
           
SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
       
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",173],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1600000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (1810357.092181787360460,5488467.918922254815698)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1810357.092, 5488467.919)
(175d29'27.21"E, 40d43'40.29"S)
Lower Left  ( 1810357.092, 5459857.919) (175d30'2.02"E, 40d59' 7.25"S)
Upper Right ( 1852287.092, 5488467.919) (175d59'12.51"E, 40d42'57.90"S)
Lower Right ( 1852287.092, 5459857.919) (175d59'54.22"E, 40d58'24.47"S)
Center      ( 1831322.092, 5474162.919) (175d44'39.06"E, 40d51' 3.45"S)
Band 1 Block=4193x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=4193x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=4193x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=4193x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
mbriggs@dev:~$

Answer (score 2):

This is 'fixed' in gdal-bin/python-gdal version 1.11.2.  The behaviour in linux using this version is the same as using oSGeo4W 1.9.2. - i.e. the tiles use the projection origin as their x=0/y=0.

Nothing I can see about it in the release notes, but clearly been resolved.